# OS X OpenGL 3.2 doesn't include glBindFragDataLocation?

Tags: macos, opengl, glsl, opengl-3

I'm trying to create a simple OpenGL 3.2 core profile application on OS X.  I'm using SDL2 via Macports, but I doubt that matters.  My understanding is that I should be using GLSL `#version 150` and my trivial fragment shader currently looks like this:

```
#version 150

out vec4 outputF;

void main() {
    outputF = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Now I believe I need to tell OpenGL that the fragment color is being set in `outputF` via the `glBindFragDataLocation` function.  The problem is that it doesn't seem to be declared anywhere.  Is this function not available in the 3.2 core profile (contrary to my searching), or am I missing a header file, or what?

Comment: Since you have established GLSL 1.5 as the baseline for this shader, you can skip having to use `glBindFragDataLocation (...)` altogether and use `layout (location = 0) out vec4 outputF;`. Be aware, that the first used `out` variable in a fragment shader is bound to color buffer 0 to begin with, so in most applications where you are only writing to a single color buffer you do not need to mess with binding locations in the first place. It is good form to set the binding location, but definitely not always necessary.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Thanks, but I get a shader compiler error when specifying the layout specification you suggest that simply reads `Invalid use of layout 'location'`.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman, layout qualifiers are not supported by GLSL 1.50. On my machine `#extension GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location : enable` after the `#version` declaration works; And `#version 330` appears to work to some extent as well - Vendor drivers? Neither can be relied on with GL 3.2.

Comment: @BrettHale: Yeah, you are right. I always forget that GLSL 330 is when this qualifier was promoted to core; probably because although OS X 10.7/8 is OpenGL 3.2 (GLSL 150) it actually does support this feature across the board. It does require the `#extension` compiler directive as you mentioned, though.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman (for deferred renderers) `glBindFragDataLocation()` is to my mind far more desirable as it reduces coupling, by removing the necessity to match `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENTn` in application code with a location in shader code. This means you can generalise application code, e.g. for rendering engines. Reusable code cannot but be a win.

Comment: @ArcaneEngineer: That's a valid point, though I work with a material system that spits out dynamic shaders and it can also be useful to handle the whole process in the generated text output. This is the sort of reason both options are available. Though my original point was that `outputF` is automagically assigned a binding location, that's just not behavior you should rely on because it is not well defined (e.g. some implementations assign locations in alphabetical order, others by order of use). Better to be explicit about these locations in an MRT application.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Indeed. I did wonder briefly after posting if you were using such a system; I have one planned myself and saw how the layout qualifiers in shader code could be useful once I implement that. Good to have both options. Appreciate the response as it confirmed my suspicion!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're on OS X, you include the `<OpenGL/gl3.h>` header for the GL 3.2 (core) profile. As part of the OpenGL framework, it is to be found in:

`/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers/gl3.h`

If you are writing the fragment to the default framebuffer, you don't need this call. That is, `outputF` will be bound to the 'color number' `(0)` by default. IIRC, you can call this `out` variable anything you please, so long as it doesn't begin with the reserved `gl_` prefix.

I'm haven't tried out SDL2 yet - but you might want to add `#define GL3_PROTOTYPES` first, e.g.,

```
#define GL3_PROTOTYPES

#if defined (__APPLE_CC__)
#include <OpenGL/gl3.h>
#else
#include <GL/glcorearb.h> // assert GL 3.2 core profile available...
#endif
```

Comment: The only thing I would add to the discussion of how/what to call the `out` variable is that fragment shader output in GLSL cannot be: 1. double-precision floating-point (Unextended GLSL 1.5 has no notion of double-precision, so this does not much matter), 2. a matrix, 3. a structure.

Comment: Also, from what I recall of Apple's porting documentation they suggest `__APPLE_CC__` only be used to distinguish the compiler version, and `__APPLE__` be used for any code that is platform-specific. It probably makes no difference in most cases, but one (`__APPLE__`) is merely a boolean where as the other has numerical meaning (`__APPLE_CC__`). It may be possible when cross-compiling something for OS X or using a compiler other than the gcc/clang stuff that ships with Xcode that `__APPLE__` is defined but `__APPLE_CC__` is not (for instance when using Intel C++).

Comment: Thanks.  I'm still a bit confused about why `glBindFragDataLocation` isn't available, but I'll just move on with my life since I don't need it.